# Mac / OS X Finder regularly jumps down or changes selection in the file list (annoyance)

Tags: macos, finder

I have this annoying problem with Finder on Snow Leopard. Every time I activate a Finder window and for example navigate to a folder, a few seconds later the selection or scroll will jump down in the list. It is like something is changed with the folder and the position is resetted or changed.

Anyone know what causes this? Is Finder detecting some constant change in the folder that I cannot see? Folder Actions?

Answer (score 3):

Are your folders organized by size? If organized by size, especially if *Calculate all sizes* is selected in the folder options, then folders will jump around as size values are calculated and reordered.

Comment: If you're in list view this will be pretty obvious. However, it can also happen in column view. Hit Command-J or use the action menu to choose Arrange by Name instead.

Comment: +1 for @fideli and @NReilingh for teaching me something new about Finder.